# Cloud9 and MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, cloud9-ide, mlab

I have set up clould9 account, and mongolab account. I fill with some items as shown below:

[image]

So everything is good. This is shown also in Mongo lab:

[image]

The problem is when I call:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection(MONGO.connectionString(), MONGO.options);


// When successfully connected
db.on('connected', function () {  
   console.log('Mongoose default connection');
   console.log(mongoose.connection);
   require('./SchemaMovie');
});
```

and this outputs me:

```
{ base: 
   { connections: [ [Circular], [Object] ],
     plugins: [],
     models: {},
     modelSchemas: {},
     options: { pluralization: true } },
  collections: {},
  models: {},
  config: { autoIndex: true },
  replica: false,
  hosts: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  user: null,
  pass: null,
  name: null,
  options: null,
  otherDbs: [],
  _readyState: 0,
  _closeCalled: false,
  _hasOpened: false,
  _listening: false }
```

Any Ideas why I do not see the collection Movie there (collections: {})? Did I skip anything?

Comment: As I cannot post answer (for some reason), I had taken time to write an answer how I manage to get it working : http://jsfiddle.net/9hkb1uu1/

Answer (score 1):

Posted from OP's comment:

Fix the model should be written as:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:  String,
    titleURL: String,
    description:   String,
    folder:   String,
    year:  Number,
    duration:  Number,
    video720p:  String,
    trailer:  String,
    poster:  String,
    language:  String,
    dateAdded: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    genres: [String],
    imdb: {
        rating: Number,
        src: String
    }
}, { collection : 'Movie' });

movieSchema.statics.listMovies = function (type, count, limit, cb) {
     return this.model('Movie').find({}, cb);
}

var Movie = mongoose.connection.model('Movie', movieSchema);
module.exports = Movie;
```

the cornerstone seems to be this one:

```
, { collection : 'Movie' }
```

Also it seems that the models should be added when a connection open, and models are set only for that mongoose connection. So I needed to change:

`var db = mongoose.createConnection(MONGO.connectionString(), MONGO.options);`

to

```
mongoose.connect(MONGO.connectionString(), MONGO.options);
```

or in the model to do

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection(MONGO.connectionString(), MONGO.options);
....
var Movie = db.model('Movie', movieSchema);
module.exports = Movie;
```

So I ended having this code:

```
mongoose.connect(MONGO.connectionString(), MONGO.options);

mongoose.connection.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log('open');
    var Movie = require('./SchemaMovie');
    var query = Movie.find({});
    query.exec(function (err, movie) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        }
         console.log(movie);
    });
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('MongoDB error: %s', err);
});
```

as connection